# How do I retrieve quoteIds for specific client(customer) in Smart Quotes?

Tags: api, xtrf

I am trying to retrieve a list with all quote ids for a specific customer.

It seems there is no API operation for Quotes(Smart)(v2) in Home Portal Api documentation to perform that, only retrieving details for a given quote:
GET **/v2/quotes/{quoteId}**

Is it possible for this operation to be added?

Answer (score 2):

1. Have a view defined in the Home Portal that produces a list of all
   quotes with their ids for your client.
2. Learn the view's id.
3. Use [Browser method](https://presentation.dev.xtrf.eu/api/doc/users/pages/browser.html) to retrieve the quotes list.