# How to get job id of existing job in XTRF smart project

Tags: xtrf

I would like to update the status of existing jobs in XTRF smart projects using the XTRF Home Portal API. The API call requires a job ID, but I don't where to find this ID.

End point:
`.../v2/jobs/{jobId}/status`

Following the solution of [a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50527663/how-do-i-retrieve-quoteids-for-specific-clientcustomer-in-smart-quotes), I have defined a view with a list of jobs that require updating. However, there seems to be no column that holds the {jobId} that is required for the API. There is a column called "Internal ID" that contains a 4-digit number. But when I use that number in the API call, there's an error:

> "Invalid Job ID of a Smart Job. Use new form of Job ID for Smart Jobs (e.g. 2QROVSCO3ZG3NM6KAZZBXH5HMI)."

So apparently, there is a new form for the job ID. Is there a specific column for the view that I should use, or is there another way to retrieve this job ID?

Answer (score 0):

The Job ID can be found in the url (after clicking on a job):
*https://[your xtrf url]/xtrf/faces/projectAssistant/projects/project.seam?assistedProjectId=5GB3QLPO2QROVSCOR55O3WJVU2Y#/project?jobs=DZAGF2QROVSCOVBJPG2UVBCJZ4II*

The Job ID is DZAGF2QROVSCOVBJPG2UVBCJZ4II

Another way is to retrieve the jobs by the API itself, this can be done for a quote, but also for a project:

Endpoint: */v2/quotes/{quoteId}/jobs*